# How to use Selenium with drop-down list that has no <select>

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am scrapping [this page](https://www.joybuy.com/1178507.html?isActivitying=false) (Joybuy) with Selenium and Beautifulsoup

I want to get the cost of shipping to certain countries.

The problem that I can make Selenium open the dialog and click on the shipping countries list but I can't make it click on certain countries, here is my code.

```
#libraries imported before the code
path_to_firefox = '/var/py/web_scraping/geckodriver'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = path_to_firefox)
browser.get('https://www.joybuy.com/1178507.html?isActivitying=false')  

elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('sdc-prompt') 
elem.click()

elem2 = browser.find_element_by_class_name('j-country-sel') 
elem2.click()
```

How can I then go through this list and choose?

Comment: You need to write a custom method for working with this drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. It should fix the errors. Lets consider we would like to select the country `Brazil`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.joybuy.com/1178507.html?isActivitying=false') 
browser.find_element_by_class_name('sdc-prompt').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".select.j-country-sel").click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".pop-ship .fn-ovs [name='Brazil']").click()  #select any country by changing the name
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Did you try the script?